# stl files are too big in rviz

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

im putting my stl filesin my urdf file but when i see it in rviz ,its too large.can someone help me with it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253869/stl-files-are-too-big-in-rviz/) by [yams](https://answers.ros.org/users/29266/yams/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS uses SI units for everything, so also in URDF (for link lengths) and for meshes. See [REP-003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html), section *Units*.

You'll have to make sure your meshes use *metres* as scale. Meshes exported by CAD tools often use *millimetres*, so they will be a 1000 times too large.

---

If you don't want to or can't scale your meshes, you could use the `scale` attribute on the `mesh` element in your urdf. See [wiki/urdf/XML/link - Elements](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/link#Elements) for more information.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0